How to stop further processing after catching exceptions in Dart HTTP requests?
I'm working on a Dart application where I make HTTP POST requests to deduct an amount from a user's balance. I'm using the http package to make the requests. However, I'm encountering a problem with how exceptions are handled. Sometimes the action is performed without giving any exceptions. But sometimes it shows an exception message in Utils but also hits on the backend and deducts the amount.
Here is my current code for deducting an amount from the server:
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deductAmountFromServer(String rfid, int balance,
  int userIndex, int deductAmount, String activationDate) async {
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(AppUrl.deductAmountEndPoint);
    final Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
      'rfid': rfid,
      'balance': "$balance",
      'userindex': "$userIndex",
      'deductamount': "$deductAmount",
      'activationdate': activationDate,
    };

    return await http
        .post(
          url,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(payload),
        )
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 15))
        .then((response) {
      // Handle successful HTTP response
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return data;
      } else {
        return {
          'status': '0',
          'message': 'Failed to deduct amount. Please try again later.',
        };
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      if (error is TimeoutException) {
        return {
          'status': '0',
          'message': 'Transaction timed out. Please try again later.',
        };
      } else {
        return {
          'status': '0',
          'message':
              'An error occurred during the transaction. Please try again later.',
        };
      }
    });
}

